# Gamemaker Studio 2 bits randomly getting deleted

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I am a student building a senior project in Gamemaker Studio for our capstone project as part of my Game Development concentration.

I am in charge of sprite creation, and currently, it is randomly deleting bits as I draw. So I will draw a couple of bits, and then it will randomly remove the surrounding bits of color. I am becoming increasingly irritated at this and I have no idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Effectively, I am designing a character and I'm trying to give his arms a bit more depth so I give him a few more tan-colored muscles. As I do, it erases the rest of his arm.

Comment: Assuming by draw, you mean you're using the sprite editor. Perhaps it's a setting that you're turned on by accident. Having an screenshot, gif or video of the problem would help a lot to show the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the Sprite Editor, then I recommend you using a different program for the sprites, as that one is completely garbage. I'm using Paint.net, its free and works in a similar way like the gms2 sprite editor but better. more plugins, more effects, better shortcut handlings.

If you still wanna stick to the gms2 sprite editor then I'll recommend restarting the game first. that's a problem I never had. Maybe you should check if you are drawing in different layers, and the blend modes of the layers. also maybe your brush is not just a pixel, but maybe a bigger brush.